# How do I backup a ruby website with a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have followed an online tutorial and created a website with ruby on rails. I want to save the completed project. However, I am performing some tweaks such as installing omniauth. I want to keep a backup, though, of the completed tutorial files.

I put all the files in a backup folder. However, what about the database? I do not fully understand migrations, but what will happen to the database when I attempt to backup the project?

Can I copy all the files from the folder to another folder, and just run everything from there? Will everything be stored? Will I need to run migrations or anything to get the site backup running?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: the default database.

Comment: Rails default database is SQLite. An SQLite database is based on a single file, usually stored in db/ directory. Copying this directory you'll have all your data.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for SQLite but if thats what you are using as a database then you can just copy the entire project folder somewhere else (or rename it) and you can run that and the database will still be there.